# Powershell redirect stderr and stdout to two different places

Tags: powershell, stdout, stderr

How do redirect

- stderr to logfile
- stdout to object

Things I've looked at:

`>>` and `2>>` only redirect to file .
 `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-RedirectStandardError` only redirect to file again.
 `| Out-File` cannot redirect stderr.
 `| Tee-Object` same issue.

Comment: `. {$object = command} 2>&1 | Out-File logfile`

Comment: @PetSerAl - can you explain this?  `2>1` would be redirecting both outputs stdout and stderr to the logfile wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes. But the assignment operation (`$object =`) already captures the regular output, so it's already removed from the output streams at that point.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Got it working. Very pithy solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Joining `stdout` and `stderr` output streams works like PetSerAl commented, though the syntax is not the most intuitive.

The weirdish syntax of `2>&1` means that `stderr` (stream 2) is to be added into the `stdout` (stream 1). As this is not actually what you are after, try adapting the other example from the MS page to Powershell:

> Or, you can redirect the output to one place, and the errors to another.
>
> dir file.xxx > output.msg 2> output.err

Thus,

```
$ret = myCommand 2> errors.log
```

should send errors in a log file and non-errors in the `$ret` variable.

Comment: Thanks vonPryz.  One the big problems i'm finding with powershell is not finding documentation on what to do, but "why" and "how" things work.  Knowing 2>&1 feeds stderr into stdout is key.

Answer (score 7):

A comprehensive explanation in [about_Redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) MSDN article.

[A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (*`stdout` to pipe*):

```
PS D:\PShell> -1,5,0,2| ForEach-Object { 15/$_ } 2>"$env:temp\err.txt" | Write-Output
-15
3
7.5

PS D:\PShell> Get-Content "$env:temp\err.txt"
Attempted to divide by zero.
At line:1 char:28
+ -1,5,0,2| ForEach-Object { 15/$_ } 2>"$env:temp\err.txt" | Write-Outpu ...
+                            ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException


PS D:\PShell>
```

Another example (*`stdout` to object*):

```
PS D:\PShell> $x = -1,5,0,2| ForEach-Object { 15/$_} 2>"$env:temp\err.txt"

PS D:\PShell> $x
-15
3
7.5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function GetAnsVal {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.Object[]][AllowEmptyString()]$Output,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.String]$firstEncNew,
          [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][System.String]$secondEncNew
    )
    function ConvertTo-Encoding ([string]$From, [string]$To){#"UTF-8" "CP866" "ASCII" "windows-1251"
        Begin{
            $encFrom = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($from)
            $encTo = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($to)
        }
        Process{
            $Text=($_).ToString()
            $bytes = $encTo.GetBytes($Text)
            $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert($encFrom, $encTo, $bytes)
            $encTo.GetString($bytes)
        }
    }
    $all = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object];
    $exception = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object];
    $stderr = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object];
    $stdout = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    $i = 0;$Output | % {
        if ($_ -ne $null){
            if ($_.GetType().FullName -ne 'System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord'){
                if ($_.Exception.message -ne $null){$Temp=$_.Exception.message <#| ConvertTo-Encoding $firstEncNew $secondEncNew#>;$all.Add($Temp);$exception.Add($Temp)}
                elseif ($_ -ne $null){$Temp=$_ <#| ConvertTo-Encoding $firstEncNew $secondEncNew#>;$all.Add($Temp);$stdout.Add($Temp)}
            } else {
                #if (MyNonTerminatingError.Exception is AccessDeniedException)
                $Temp=$_.Exception.message <#| ConvertTo-Encoding $firstEncNew $secondEncNew#>;
                $all.Add($Temp);$stderr.Add($Temp)
            }   
         }
    $i++
    }
    [hashtable]$return = @{}
    $return.Meta0=$all;$return.Meta1=$exception;$return.Meta2=$stderr;$return.Meta3=$stdout;
    return $return
}
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
& C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe 'api.ipify.org/?format=plain' 2>&1 | set-variable Output;
$r = & GetAnsVal $Output
[Console]::Write("exception:`n");
$r.Meta1
[Console]::Write("stderr:`n");
$r.Meta2
[Console]::Write("stdout:`n");
$r.Meta3
```